# ViewController Relationship only on Phone Device's

Tags: xcode, swift, size-classes

I try to force an TabBarItem only that it should only show itself when the device is an iphone and not an iPad.

I try to do this ith size classes but this dosen't work.
I also tried to delete the TabBarItem so:

```
class TabController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if ScreenTyp.isPad() {
        print("Device is iPad")
        removeTab(1);
    } else {
        print("Device is iPhone")
    }
}

func removeTab(index:Int) {
    if var items = tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem]? {
        if items.count > 0 {
            items.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}
}
```

but this also doesn't work.

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: Does your class ScreenTyp return the correct value for isPad() ? Does the code removeTab get called? if you put a breakpoint on items.removeAtIndex(index) - does your application get this far?

Comment: Yes, my application get's so far